# A SQL query that does not work for getting number of orders in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This is a part of SQL coding project of database.

I need to design a single table to hold orders made by customers.
Assume that customers' details (e.g. names)  are stored in another table.

Using the table that I designed for orders, and this assumed other table, write
a single SQL query that can give the number of orders for every customer, one line per customer.

The “Orders” table

```
 Order_ID   Order_NO    Customer_ID
 1            8088            3
 2            9632            1
 3            1272            4
 4            6037            1
```

Assume that the customer names and other details (address, phone numbers, emails) are stored in the “Customers” table.

My SQL:

```
 SELECT Customers.FirstName, Customers.FirstName, Orders.OrderNo
 FROM Customers
 FULL JOIN Orders
 ON Customers.Customer_ID = Orders.Customer_ID
 ORDER BY Customers.LastName
```

Are there something wring with it ?

Comment: Change FULL JOIN to INNER JOIN maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the query to inner join

```
SELECT 
    Customers.FirstName
    , Customers.FirstName
    , Orders.OrderNo  
FROM
    Customers  
    INNER JOIN Orders  ON Customers.Customer_ID = Orders.Customer_ID  
ORDER BY 
    Customers.LastName
```

Query for Ordercount for customer

```
SELECT 
    Customers.LastName
    ,   COUNT(Orders.Order_Id)
FROM
    Customers  
    INNER JOIN Orders  ON Customers.Customer_ID = Orders.Customer_ID  
GROUP BY
    Customers.LastName
ORDER BY 
    Customers.LastName
```

Full join

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp

Inner join

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: well mysql doesn't support full join so there's that

Comment: @rdkleine, COUNT(Orders.Order_Id) should be COUNT(Orders.Customer_Id), right ? We need to count the number of orders made by each customer.

Comment: Doesn't matter which column as long as it is from the tabel Orders. Count count's the number of times the column is found in relation to Customer

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to `COUNT` the orders you can do this:

```
SELECT 
    Customers.FirstName, 
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            Orders
        WHERE
            Orders.Customer_ID=Customers.Customer_ID
    ) AS NbrOfOrders
FROM 
    Customers
```

References:

- [12.15.1. GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: would you please explain how to use them in my code ? i am a new learner of SQL. thanks !!!